# How use Overflow Hidden and Position Absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted ***descriptionClass*** is show over ***itemClass*** when I make ***.slider-imgClass***  is **Hover** .......................
how use ***Jquery OR javascritp OR CSS*** ..............

**html**

```
   <div id="carousel-example-generic">
      <div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="carousel-example-captions">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                    <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
                  <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                     <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                   <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                   <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item ">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                    <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                   <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                   <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                   <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
          </div>
           <div class="item ">
              <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                    <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                   <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                   <div class="descriptoion">texttexfdlkfjddjkdldl<br/>djtdkdldldldldldld ldldldldlddldldldlddlld</div>
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <a data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="left carousel-control"> 
          left
         </a> 
         <a data-slide="next" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="right carousel-control"> 
          right
         </a> 

      </div>
```

**css**

```
.descriptoion{
   border: 1px solid red;
   bottom: 0;
   color: red;
   height: 250px;
   line-height: 40px;
   position: absolute;
   right: -222px;
   width: 200px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   z-index: 1000;
   background-color:#f0f0f0;
   display:none;
   font-size:20pt;
   text-align:center;
  }
.descriptoion:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid #f0f0f0;
    top:50%;
    left:-42px;
    z-index:1000;
  }
 .descriptoion:after{
    border:22px solid transparent;
    border-right:22px solid red;
    z-index:10001;
    content: "";
    left: -46px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 49%;
    z-index: 1;
 }
.slider-img:hover .descriptoion{
    display:block;
}
```

**jquery**

```
   $(".slider-img").hover(function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('not-overflow');
   });
   $(".carousel > a").click(function(){
      $(".carousel-inner").removeClass("not-overflow");
  });
```

i have this problem
    [image]

i wanted this style

[image]

## [UPDATEDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/e2S53/1/)

Comment: But it is not ok because it is have scroll.

Comment: how use jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to remove the `overflow:hidden` property from `.item-active` and also from `.carousel-inner`. 
If you see the cycle image breaking out of the div, limit the size of that image.

Also you seem to be having repetitive classes in your css file.

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e2S53/3/)

Comment: hey but your answer is not prefect because i am .item-active is scroll when i am click leftarrow..

Comment: You have to get rid of overflow:hidden. It may lead to breaking a few other things. But you will have to find a workaround for those without this.

Comment: i not use scroll when i am click leftarrow, .item-active slide is not use scroll. how use sir,

Comment: @theinlwin: The updated fiddle seems to have the same code? What is the issue that you are facing if you remove the overflow?

Comment: yes sir, i wanted overflow:hidden is remove when .slider-img is hover, and, i wanted overflow:hidden is use when .left is click, that is it ok.

Comment: But also it is not ok